# Can't use sympy.preview due to LaTeX

Tags: python, sympy, preview

I'm trying to convert a latex form equation into an image using `sympy.preview` in the following code:

```py
import sympy

x,y = sympy.symbols('x y')
sympy.preview("$3 x + \frac{y^{2}}{5}$",output='png')
```

but I get `RuntimeError: latex program is not installed` error, Any solutions?

I tried converting the latex equation into a sympy equation using `eval()` but didn't work either.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 11